# Laravel Eloquent: When() on a JSONB column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I don't think I understand the proper use of `when()`.

I'm trying to use it in this fashion:
I have a `jsonb` column (called `info`) which has multiple properties. I want to check if one of the values is 'Chemical' and perform some query. Otherwise, perform another query. This is how I am using it:

```php
$query->when(
    'info->type' === 'Chemical',
    function ($query) {
        return $query->has('bottles', 0);
    },
    function ($query) {
        return $query->where('info->quantity', '<=', 0);
    }
);
```

The first function would be the truthy value and the second function would be falsey. However, it never hits the first function.

What am I doing wrong? Is this not how you use `when`?

Comment: The first argument of your `when()` clause is currently `'info->type' === 'Chemical'`, which is `false`; the strings do not equal each other. If you need to apply a condition based on if `info->type` is `Chemical` **in the database**, you probably need a `case` statement of some kind, but I'm not sure of the syntax off the top of my head for that.

Comment: @TimLewis, yes, the latter is what I want. I'll search around for 'case' usage in Eloquent but if you do remember, please don't hesitate to direct me here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the only error is that `info->type` is never going to be equal to `Chemical` because you are comparing strings.

So, whatever you write as the expression, it must literally be something that has nothing to do with the query.

`when` works as an alias of an `if`, so you don't need to break your query like this:

```php
$query = Model::query();

if ($expression) {
    $query->where('column_a', 1);
} else {
    $query->where('column_a', 0);
}

$query->where('whatever', 123);

if ($expression2) {
    $query->where('abc', 1);
}
```

Using `when`, it would be like this:

```php
$query = Model::query()
    ->when(
        $expression,
        fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('column_a', 1),
        fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('column_a', 0),
    )
    ->when(
        $expression2,
        fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('abc', 1)
    );
```

---

Following your example, you will need to get what `info->type` is, let's say you are able to get that from another part:

```php
$infoType = 'value';

$query = Model::query()
    ->when(
        $infoType === 'Chemical',
        function ($query) {
            return $query->has('bottles', 0);
        },
        function ($query) {
            return $query->where('info->quantity', '<=', 0);
        }
    );
```

More about `when` on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

You can read more by just checking the [`when()`'s source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0047667ff5aa57936bcf7c292feaf107e52dfb77/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/Traits/Conditionable.php#L21-L40) (Laravel 9)

Comment: I am  glad it did, because I was not sure how to express this, nice to help! If it did help, make sure to mark it as solved!